# How to not decode special characters in links?

Tags: html

If you save this file and hover over the link, firefox will decode `%2F%2F` to `//` and hence the link is broken.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<a href="linux%2F%2Funix_servers.html">linux%2F%2Funix_servers.html</a>
```

Are there ways to prevent the browser from decoding the special characters in links?

Comment: That may just be a visual thing. Have you actually *clicked* the link and checked how it's being received on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the URL is to contain the real percent sign “%”, then by the applicable encoding rules, it must be %-encoded, as “%25”. Thus the URL should be written as linux%252F%252Funix_servers.html

Answer (score 0):

It only displays the text of the link as // since %2f is a slash in HTML. The link itself is fine and should link to the file you had with no issue. Use `&#37;` to represent a % in html.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

    <a href="linux%2F%2Funix_servers.html">linux&#37;2F&#37;2Funix_servers.html</a>
</body>
```